# How to set permissions for passthrough USB device in libvirt LXC guest?

Tags: systemd, usb, udev, libvirt, lxc

I have an `lxc` type guest in libvirt to which I pass through a USB device like this:

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x10c4"/>
    <product id="0xea60"/>
    <address bus="1" device="10"/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
```

The device shows up as `/dev/bus/usb/001/010` like this:

```
crwx------ 1 root root 189, 9 Sep  5 23:21 /dev/bus/usb/001/010
```

Adding a udev rule like this

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", GROUP="hass", MODE="0660"
```

and then running e.g.

```
$ udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
```

does change the owner/permissions as desired. After a reboot however the permission is reset, because systemd doesn't run udev in a container by default:

```
systemd[1]: Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files was skipped because of a failed condition check (ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/sys).
```

LXC proper apparently supports directives such as `lxc.cgroup.devices.allow` to solve this issue. What is the best way to change device permissions for a libvirt LXC guest?

I'd like to avoid setting the permission via a udev rule on the libivrt host, as that would require keeping the uid/gid in sync with the guest.

The guest is Arch, the host is Debian.